# Find whether roots of an equation are real or not.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Is it possible to write, let's say :- (a^2  + 1/a^2 - 1) as (a-b)^2.

---

So I have to solve a problem (as practice, no test or assignment) that says to show if the roots of a given equation are real.

The equation is :-

$$x^2  -  2\left(m + \frac1m \right)x  + 3 = 0$$

I proceeded to solve it using the discriminant formula(b^2 - 4ac) and what I'm left with is :-

$$4\left(m^2 + \frac1{m^2}   -1\right) $$

And I have no idea what to do next, i know that for a equation to be real its discriminant has to be greater than zero, but I dont know how this would be greater or less than zero and if this is the correct answer to the problem.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Is your equation $x^2-2(m+\frac 1 m)x+3$ or $x^2-2\frac{m+1}{m}x+3$? You can use $\LaTeX$ to make these notational aspects less ambiguous.

Comment: If you can't use LaTex, add reference to an image. The equations are ambiguous.

Comment: Will look into it, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the discriminant,

$$m^2 + \frac 1{m^2}   -1 = \left(m - \frac 1m\right)^2+1>0$$

So, the roots are real.

Comment: Not sure how did you conclude the roots are real directly from the above form.

Comment: Because it is the discriminant.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Actually , I still dont understand, how do they change their signs?

Comment: @Rizwan - I did not change signs. $(m-\frac1m)^2 = m^2 + \frac1{m^2}-2$.

Comment: @Quanto - Yes I understand that you used the form (a-b)^2 but what I dont understand is how you got that form.Like that 2, and how does -1 become +1.

Comment: $m^2 + \frac 1{m^2}   -1 = \left(m - \frac 1m\right)^2+ 2 - 1=\left(m - \frac 1m\right)^2+ 1$

Comment: Yes ,thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your discriminant should be $$\left[-2\left(m+\frac1m\right)\right]^2-4(1)(3)=4\left(m^2+2m\frac1m+\frac{1}{m^2}-3\right)=4\left(m^2-1+\frac{1}{m^2}\right)=4\left(m^2-2+\frac{1}{m^2}+1\right)=4\left(m^2-2m\frac1m+\frac{1}{m^2}+1\right)=4\left(m-\frac1m\right)^2+4,$$ which is always positive, as wanted.

Answer (score 0):

As $x^2-2ax+3=0\iff (x-a)^2=a^2-3$ we'll have two solution iff $a^2>3$.  Now 
$$\left(m+\frac1m\right)^2=\left(m-\frac1m\right)^2+4.$$